# Passing a query string through redirect for maintenance mode

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am looking for some guidance when working with a maintenance mode system, utilised within a .htaccess file, via mod_rewrite and passing a `$_GET` along with it.

Passing a `$_GET` in mod_rewrite is perfectly fine under normal circumstances for me, but in this instance I am experiencing issues..

The code I have for the maintenance system is as follows:

```
RewriteCond                 %{REMOTE_HOST} !^XX\.XXX\.XXX\.XXX

RewriteCond                 %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.php$ 
RewriteCond                 %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css/.*$
RewriteCond                 %{REQUEST_URI} !^/assets/.*$ 
RewriteRule ^$              maintenance.php [R=302,L]
```

So what I need is the ability to pass a `$_GET` along with the rewriteRule, thus when the site is viewed as normal by anyone using the allowed IP, I can define that the site is being viewed in maintenance mode.

Of course people not on the allowed IP get redirected to maintenance.php file and don't need this reminder anyway, as the page does that already.

Thank you in advance anyone that can help me in this issue.

EDIT::

```
# Start the mod re-write conditions #

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\/$                         ?cat=generic&page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^products\/([^/]+)\/([^/]+)\/$      ?cat=product&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^theteam\/([^/]+)\/$                ?cat=staff&page=$1 [L]
```

Thats how I deal with the other links on my page, I hope that is all you needed to see.

Dan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !maintenance.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(css|assets).*$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^XX\.XXX\.XXX\.XXX$
RewriteRule (.*) /maintenance.php [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^XX\.XXX\.XXX\.XXX$
RewriteRule (.*) $1?mode=maintenance [L,QSA]
```

This works for me, first you have the negation redirect so whoever tries to access without the allowed IP will go to maintenance.php.

Then you have the append internal redirect, the GET `mode=maintenance` will not be visible but will be there.

And you can retrieve it with `$_GET['mode']`.

If you want it to visually append to the query string and only to php files you can use:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^XX\.XXX\.XXX\.XXX$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^mode=maintenance.*$
RewriteRule (.*) $1?mode=maintenance [R,L,QSA]
```

Update of visible rule for your sub directories format this rule should be placed before it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^XX\.XXX\.XXX\.XXX$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*mode=maintenance.*$
# for visible query string uncomment the below line and comment the next rule
#RewriteRule (.*) $1?mode=maintenance [R,L,QSA]
# for invisible query string
RewriteRule (.*) $1?mode=maintenance [L,QSA]

# Start the mod re-write conditions #

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\/$                         ?cat=generic&page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^products\/([^/]+)\/([^/]+)\/$      ?cat=product&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^theteam\/([^/]+)\/$                ?cat=staff&page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This seems to cinflict with my other rewrite redirects so if I try navigation to www.mydomain.com/products/foobar i get a 500 error. It works perfectly on the root of the domain, www.mydomain.com. Any ideas?

Comment: @DanielWrigley the rule with visible mode or invisible mode, also post your others redirect as I will need to give them a look.

Comment: post your `.htaccess` with your other rules so I can see what may be wrong.

Comment: The last update at the bottom works just fine for me with your current rules.

Comment: sorry, what I meant was I am using your invisible method and mistakenly asked for an update to the visible method which you kindly gave, ofc using the new visible method wont work with the invisible method. Is there any chance you could update your invisible method taking into account my current rules as you did before please? very very sorry.

Comment: @DanielWrigley remove the R and it will be invisible.